# Can't see Create Database in Analysis Services SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssas

When I right click on Databases in Analysis services there is no Create Database menu Item.

Another person with this problem 'reinstalled with all options' but when I run SSDT setup there is only 'do you want it or not' type options - for me anyway.

I've checked that my user login is an administrator. I've also started Management studio in administrator mode. No luck.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: Sorry Jarrod, can't understand your sentence. Do you have a problem with me asking a question? I have seen other questions about SSMS and SSAS on this site. Problem solved anyway.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this might have to do with the mode, in which SQL Server Analysis Services is installed. If it is installed in the **Tabular** mode (the default), then the `New Database...` menu item is not available. If **Multidimensional and Data Mining** mode is selected during the installation, then the `New Database...` menu item becomes available.

A much more experienced co-worker helped me to figure this out when I was struggling with the same problem.